# How do I move a child QGraphicsItem while the parent is selected?

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to extend my Qt knowledge to `QGraphicsView` by implementing a diagram-ish application. Currently I'm able to select, drag and scale rectangles using handles. The `HandleItem`s  are children to a `ManipulatorItem` which in turn scales a `DiagramItem` of choice. I want to improve this by only showing the handles when the item is selected. My problem is this:

1. If the item is selected, then the `itemChanged()` in `HandleItem` isn't called
2. If the handle item `ItemIsSelectable` flag is set, it works, but the original item is obviously deselected.

My question is: is it possible to send geometry changes to a child while the parent is still selected? Also, the handle item might also be outside the bounding rectangle of the parent item.

The `DiagramItem` has the following flags:

```
setFlags(ItemIsMovable | ItemIsSelectable);
```

The `HandleItem` has the following flags:

```
setFlags(ItemIsMovable | ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
```

Comment: I know the question is old, but, have you tried to use signals/slots to notify the children?

Comment: `QGraphicsItem`s do not support signal/slots because they do not derive from `QObject`